# Cannot Create Path Hierarchy Tokenizer in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: python, sdk, tokenize, azure-cognitive-search

I am creating an index for Azure Cognitive Search using the Python SDK. I am trying to create a custom analyzer using a custom tokenizer. My definitions are as follows

```
tokenizer = [
    {
        "name": "taxonomy_delimiter",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.path_hierarchy_v2",
        "delimiter": " ● ",
        "maxTokenLength": 10000,
    },
]
analyzer = [
    {
        "name": "taxonomy",
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "tokenizer": "taxonomy_delimiter",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "trim"
        ]
    }
]
```

When I try to run `SearchIndexClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key_admin1), api_version='2021-04-30-Preview').create_index(index)` I get the following warning and error

```
Subtype value #Microsoft.Azure.Search.path_hierarchy_v2 has no mapping, use base class LexicalTokenizer.

() The request is invalid. Details: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.Tokenizer'. Reason: Cannot create an abstract class.
```

I'm using the tokenizer as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#built-in-analyzers). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the tokenizer name instead of the tokenizer type.

Try with the below instead:

```
tokenizer = [
{
    "name": "taxonomy_delimiter",
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PathHierarchyTokenizerV2",
    "delimiter": " ● ",
    "maxTokenLength": 10000,
},
```